# Irrelevance of some data or I am missing something

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

In q17 what is the relevance of the man part.if train travels by 72 km per hr my time to cross the bridge would be (72*5/18)*120=2400 which is wrong somehow

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the length of the train. You can use the man to do that.

Comment: Oh cool.forgot about the trains length:p thanks!